# de.hybris.platform.persistence.EJBItemNotFoundException: no composed type with code CMSSite found

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I followed below steps.

a. I installed 'b2c_acc_plus' recipe.
install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus'

b. Installed accelerator module using modulegen
ant modulegen -Dinput.module=accelerator -Dinput.name=megastore -Dinput.package=com.hybris.megastore -Dinput.template=develop

c. ant clean all

d. hybrisserver.bat

When I ran the server, I seen below severe message in console log.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.103 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/megastorestorefront] threw exception [Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 7 of 16. Current filter: 'com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter@4e1baf'!; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: type code 'CMSSite' invalid] with root cause
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.103 | de.hybris.platform.persistence.EJBItemNotFoundException: no composed type with code CMSSite found.[HY-4711]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.getComposedType(TypeManagerEJB.java:476)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadAndCacheInfo(DBPersistenceManager.java:254)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.getPersistenceInfoInternal(DBPersistenceManager.java:241)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.getPersistenceInfo(DBPersistenceManager.java:202)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.typecache.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.getCachedTypeData(DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.java:151)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.104 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:75)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.createSingleType(FromClause.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translateNested(FromClause.java:70)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText$2.translate(ParsedText.java:292)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchTools.replace(FlexibleSearchTools.java:307)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2018/12/22 13:25:08.105 |     at
```

When I hit the url 'https://localhost:9002/megastorestorefront/', I seen below stack trace.

```
de.hybris.platform.persistence.EJBItemNotFoundException: no composed type with code CMSSite found.[HY-4711]
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.getComposedType(TypeManagerEJB.java:476)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadAndCacheInfo(DBPersistenceManager.java:254)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.getPersistenceInfoInternal(DBPersistenceManager.java:241)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.getPersistenceInfo(DBPersistenceManager.java:202)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.typecache.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.getCachedTypeData(DefaultFlexibleSearchTypeCacheProvider.java:151)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:89)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedType.<init>(ParsedType.java:75)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.createSingleType(FromClause.java:86)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translateNested(FromClause.java:70)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText$2.translate(ParsedText.java:292)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchTools.replace(FlexibleSearchTools.java:307)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedText.translate(ParsedText.java:286)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.FromClause.translate(FromClause.java:45)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.translate(ParsedQuery.java:467)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.ParsedQuery.getTranslatedQuery(ParsedQuery.java:237)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.flexiblesearch.QueryParser.translateQuery(QueryParser.java:233)
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.translate(FlexibleSearch.java:2001)
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1411)
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch.search(FlexibleSearch.java:1385)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:418)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService$2.execute(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:1)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSessionService.executeInLocalView(DefaultSessionService.java:89)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.getJaloResult(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:396)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.search(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:168)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.dao.AbstractItemDao.search(AbstractItemDao.java:73)
        at de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.daos.impl.DefaultCMSSiteDao.findAllCMSSites(DefaultCMSSiteDao.java:39)
        at de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.services.impl.DefaultCMSSiteService.getSites(DefaultCMSSiteService.java:278)
        at de.hybris.platform.cms2.servicelayer.services.impl.DefaultCMSSiteService.getSiteForURL(DefaultCMSSiteService.java:230)
        at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.context.impl.DefaultContextInformationLoader.initializeSiteFromRequest(DefaultContextInformationLoader.java:96)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.processNormalRequest(CMSSiteFilter.java:173)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:128)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.HybrisSpringSessionFilter.doFilter(HybrisSpringSessionFilter.java:69)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:206)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.hybris.megastore.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can any one tell me the reason for this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: You probably have to run init

Comment: Hi B.M, thanks for the reply. I tried ant initialize, but issue is not resolved. any other suggestions will be appreciated..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the error by importing below statement from admin console.

```
# CMS Site
UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];urlPatterns;
;electronics;(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=electronics)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://electronics\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://api\.hybrisdev\.com(:[\d]+)?/rest.*$,(?i)^https?://[^/]*/megastorestorefront((?![\?\&]site=).)*;
```

If you are using default store front, import below information.

```
# CMS Site
UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];urlPatterns;
;electronics;(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=electronics)(|\&.*)$,(?i)^https?://electronics\.[^/]+(|/.*|\?.*)$,(?i)^https?://api\.hybrisdev\.com(:[\d]+)?/rest.*$,(?i)^https?://[^/]*/yacceleratorstorefront((?![\?\&]site=).)*;
```